# How to add GUI components in FireMonkey

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-xe5

I have started a new *FireMonkey Desktop Application* in C++Builder XE5 Update 2. I changed the settings *Use dynamic RTL* to unchecked, and *Link with runtime packages* to unchecked (otherwise the program gives access violation on startup when run), but other than that, made no changes.

The program runs OK as a blank form with nothing on it. Based on internet tutorials, it looks like it should be possible to add controls to the form in the same way as a VCL application. However nothing appears in my tool palette:

[image: Tool Palette]

Only the "Frames" is there and no other controls. If I try to add a Frames it says `No frames are available to insert. New frames may be created from the File|New|Other selections..`

When I go to File|New|Other|FireMonkey Frame, the error occurs `Error creating form: Access violation at address 0B6CD96E in module 'fmxdesigner190.bpl'. Read of address 00000000.`

How do I add controls to the Form?

Comment: That is not normal. It looks like something is messed up in your C++ Builder installation.

Comment: @SebastianZ OK, maybe I will try to reinstall.  Is there any utility like `sfc` for Windows that will inspect whether all my files are present and not corrupt?